# case-sensitive filter is not working when used with JSearch in marklogic:

Tags: marklogic

I have tried the following code for case-sensitive search in marklogic using javascript.

```js
 jsearch.documents().where(cts.wordQuery("automobile",["case-sensitive"]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Passing the case-sensitive option on the word query is necessary but -- if the database only has case-insensitive indexing -- not sufficient for case-sensitive search.

If the database hasn't been indexed to support case-sensitive searches, one expedient short-term development-time workaround is to add filtering on the result set by chaining a [`filter()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/DocumentsSearch.filter) call after the `where()` call and before the `result()` call.

For more information about `filter()`, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/DocumentsSearch.filter

For good performance at scale, however, the database should be indexed for fast case sensitive searches instead of using filtering.  See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/text_index#id_24289

For more information about unfiltered searching, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered

Hoping that helps,